# Failing to delete Network Interface AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am trying to delete my vpc and I first need to delete my network interface. However, those cannot be deleted because they are still in use. I terminated all my ec2 instances and still, the interfaces are in use and cannot be detached even cannot be forced detached. They are of the type efs mount target.[image]
[image: Here is a view of the network interface]

Comment: Suspect that if you want to delete the ENIs you first need to delete the related EFS mount targets.

Comment: @jarmod and how do you do that?

Comment: @koFTT see the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those interfaces are currently `in-use` and you cannot delete them directly.

1. You can select each interface and check **which resources** are
   using right now. As I can see at the description part, `EFS` service
   and it's not related to `EC2` services.
2. Each `EFS` filesystem has a network interface (ENI) per its subnet for communication. If you
   want to remove those interfaces, you need to delete the `EFS`
   filesystem first.

[image: EFSENIs]